# How do devices recognize their chargers?

Tags: charging

Several android devices complain when they are not plugged into their manufacturer-designated chargers. One samsung tablet I own won't even charge if its not on its own brand charger.

Is there some code between the device and charger, or is it just the voltage / amperage gauges?

Comment: I know that on some samsung devices the charging pins are longer. So the device can tell if the original charger or another generic charger with shorter pins has been added.

Comment: Hum, Samsung is going the 90's Microsoft rabbit hole all the way (and we all know how it ends) but some Motorola devices also b** about the chargers too. So its not a Samsung specific question (hence no Samsung tags).

Comment: Yes there are parity strands in some cables that allows the device to identify if its own cable or not. I don't understand why manufacturers have to be like that but they are. I know devices that use the same exact cable (voltage and plug type) but they can't be interchanged, its ridiculous.